# Bitbucket submodules wont delete

Tags: git, bitbucket

I accidentally pushed a couple folders to bitbucket that had .git folders in them because I cloned them using git clone.

[image]

I can't click these folders or go into them in bitbucket

what do I do to get rid of those I already used:

```
rm -rf .git
```

for those two .git folders
then:

```
git reset --hard ^HEAD
git push
git commit -a -m "Message"
git push
```

I also have tried setting the commit back one but that didn't work either.
there are no submodule files for these I've also moved the folders from there directory and made another push yet they still apear.

Comment: Well besides fixes in Git, you can strip the changes on the public repo on bitbucket

Comment: I've rolled back my commit on bitbucket yet the changes are still there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not "folders with .git" you see on the bitbucket site.

Those are **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

And removing the `.git` and pushing won't change that, since:

- the `.gitmodules` of your main repo still does declare said submodules
- the index still contain a [special entry (gitlink, mode 160000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)

To remove a submodule, see "[How do I remove a Git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309)" (git 1.8.5+):

```
git submodule deinit asubmodule    
git rm asubmodule
# Note: asubmodule (no trailing slash)
# or, if you want to leave it in your working tree
git rm --cached asubmodule
```

Then commit and push.

Comment: Tried this .gitmodule was never there in the first place. ran git ls-files --stage | grep 160000  with no results tried removing from cache and re pushing using -f and it didn't work

Comment: @Snowfiring if you were to clone your repo now, would you still see those entries? I don't have access to your repo to have a look myself apparently.

Comment: No they are not there if I clone, they seem to have deleted over night

Comment: Yep but for no reason I'm not quite sure how that worked, or why it took overnight to update those particular files

Comment: @Snowfiring I suspect the screenshot you have in your question doesn't reflect the HEAD (latest) of master, so maybe those submodule references were deleted since then, which means a fresh clone will work.