# BitBucket - submodule not download when using git clone

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm a new user of Bitbucket and also new with Git. In my project repository I use modules which are in separate folders. But some of this folders are not clickable, they only show the name with an arrow + number.
Who can explain me what this means?

I understood that this is submodules, but when I use git clone to another folder in my computer its not downloaded. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to `git clone` including submodules?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3796927/124319) (answer: `git clone --recursive`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the submodule references a SHA1 of another repo. That is the SHA1 you see after the arrow.
This is a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309), called **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**.

You can see those in the question "[Bitbucket submodules wont delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24073937/6309)".

[image: example]

When you clone a repo with submodule, you need to add:

```
git submodule update --init
```

*Then* you would see the content of the submodule, [as a detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).